# Compute "substring" distances between sequences

Tags: traminer

My dataset (first line = header) is the following:

```
ID;Activity 1;Activity 2; ... ;Activity 20;
Company_X;A1A3T1D1O1R1R8;A1A3T2O1R2;...;A1A3T6D2O1O2R2
Company_Y;A1A3T1O1R1;A1A3T2O1R2;...;A1A3T11O1O3R5
Company Z;A1A3T1D8O1R1R8;A1A3T2O1R2;...;A1A3T6D2O1R2
```

where for each activity, each pair (one letter + one number) represents on part of a sequence. A1=actor1, A3=actor3, O1=object1. What I try to do is to compute the difference between the activities of companies. For instance the activity1 of company_x should have a difference of - e.g., 2 with the activity1 of company_y since they have in common A1A3T1O1R1 but not D1 and R8.

Can any packages in TraMineR do that? Which means comparing, within each event, a predefined number of chars?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I cannot figure out what you want to do. What is your alphabet? What is the string A1A3T6D2O1O2R2? Is it a sequence or is it an element of the alphabet? In this latter case, is it a state or an event, or in other words, does the position in the sequence convey time information?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gilbert. You are right, more explanations would have helped. Each pair (one letter + one number) represent an entity of a sequence. A1=actor1, A3=actor3, O1=object1. What I try to do is to compute the difference between the activities of companies. For instance the activity1 of company_x should have a difference of e.g., 2 with the activity1 of company_y since they have in common A1A3T1O1R1 but not D1 and R8. The combination of pairs are then a sequence. Hope it is clearer

Comment: You should edit the question to make that clear and to allow me to remove my down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, each string (activity) like `A1A3T6D2O1O2R2` should be considered as a sequence of pairs and you want to compare such sequences.

The `seqdef` function of TraMineR can read sequences in string form. However, when each element is defined by more than a single character, you have to introduce a separator (e.g., A1-A3-T6) for that. Then, to pair your sequences with company names you may also need to organize your data in table form with each sequence (activity) in a separate row, something like

```
ID         Activity
company_x  A1-A3-T6-D2-O1-O2-R2
company_y  A1-A3-T1-O1-R1
...
```

Then, you can compute dissimilarities using measures applicable to sequences of different lengths. Optimal matching (OM), for instance, is the minimal cost of transforming one sequence into the other given the indel and substitution costs. This should give you what you expect. Depending on the substitution costs, the distance between A1A3T6D2O1O2R2 and A1A3T6D2O1R2, could be different than between A1A3T6D2O1O2R2 and A3T4

Comment: It is exactly what I needed, thank you very much. A table is required